# How to take screenshot and take action based on it in Appium using javascript?

Tags: javascript, android, appium

Appium claims that the whole setup is this easy:

```
brew install node      # get node.js
npm install -g appium  # get appium
npm install wd         # get appium client
appium &               # start appium
node your-appium-test.js
```

Well, I have `Node.js` already. But how do I write that test?

I need to take a screenshot, evaluate it's contents and then emulate screen tap action based on the contents. How can I do it? Can you at least point me in the right direction?

I have read "[Get started](http://appium.io/getting-started.html)" on Appium homepage but I don't feel started at all.

Comment: Can you check out this link - http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2015/09/appium-tutorials.html

Comment: @Tomas Zato : Also you can find some sample code here "https://github.com/appium/sample-code/tree/master/sample-code/examples" to dive into the language of your interest. :)

Comment: find step by step guide here. [Appium Tutorial](http://www.testautomationsimplified.com/appium-tutorial/)